# Is bitcoin the only entrance to buying other coins?

Tags: trading

I am totally newbie and looking into buying some other coins such as Megacoin and Quark with my bank account. After some research, I found that the only way to buy those coins seems to be buying them with Bitcoin.

Are there ways for me to directly buy other coins?

Answer (score 1):

You can find coin exchange who sell those alt coins, see at MtGox or BTC-e
other ways to get alt coin such as Megacoin and Quark is by mining that coin

Comment: Can I buy those coins directly with paypal?

Comment: @ethanjyx 99% sure no, you won't be able to buy crypto-currencies using paypal or a credit card. Since buyers can ask for a chargeback with these payment methods whereas the coins can't, most coin sellers are too afraid to accept them.